# How to add Onclick event to c3 chart in Shiny, R?

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, c3.js

I want to add onclick event to c3.js chart in Shiny R. I`v read this [article with c3 examples](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/js-send-message.html) and try to do some simple app with print in console when clicked on chart. 
But in my case, onclick I have
[this error in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6R63A.png). Could you, please, say what I do wrong?

```
    ##devtools::install_github("mrjoh3/c3")
    library(c3)
    library(shiny)

    shinyApp(
        ui = fluidPage(
            c3Output("c3test")
        ),
        server = function(input, output, session) {
          output$c3test <- renderC3({
            pie.chart <- data.frame(sugar=20,fat=45,salt=10) %>% 
              c3(onclick="function(d,element) {
                 console.log(d.id);
          }") %>% 
                    c3_donut()
        })
        }
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the author of c3 library for shiny **[mrjoh3](https://github.com/mrjoh3/c3/issues/6)**. He helped me find the right way, how to add JS function to c3 charts. Just need to put JS function into htmlwidgets::JS() function like here:

```
c3(data, onclick = htmlwidgets::JS('function(d, element){console.log(d.id)}'))
```